# How do looping to match some file with a string in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have some file in a folder, the format name file is like this

```
US0908ABC
US0908DEF
US0908GHI
```

I want to do looping to check whether those file match with 2 variable that I already initialize. 
If the file match with my variable, it will return the file that matched.

This is what I've done. I used this code, I can matching those file with my variable, but only checking 1 variable, not checking both of my variable.

```
$Variable_1 = "US"
$Variable_2 = "0908"
$Path = "C:\Doc\File"
$SW = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path
if($SW -match $Variable_1 -and $Variable_2)
{   $SW
    Write-Host "Found"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Check Again!"
}
```

### Updated

```
Function Check
{
    $n = 0
    while (-not (Test-Path -Path $Path)) {
        Start-Sleep -s 5
        $n++
        Foreach($File in $SW) {
            If(($File.Name -match $Variable_1) -and ($File.Name -match $Variable_2)){
                Write-Host ">>file Found: $File"
            }
        }
    }
    Write-Host ">>File found after $n attempts"
    return $true
}

$Variable_1 = "US"
$Variable_2 = "0908"
$Path = "C:\Doc\File"
$SW = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path
If(Check)
{
    Write-Host ">>Found"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Not Found"
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for folder names or file names?

Answer (score 2):

You can go with:

```
$Variable_1 = "US"
$Variable_2 = "0908"
$Path = "C:\Doc\File"
$SW = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path

$SW | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Name.Contains($Variable_1) -and $_.Name.Contains($Variable_2)) {   
        $_
        Write-Host "Found"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Check Again!"
    }
}
```

A much more simpler approach can be coded in one line:

```
  $foundFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Doc\File" | Where-Object {$_.Name.Contains("US") -and $_.Name.Contains("0908") }
```

`$foundFiles` is of type `array` and includes all filtered files. You can iterate via `$foundFiles` either via a [for loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-6), or via a [foreach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-6), or via the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet in combination with pipeline operation (e.g. `$foundFiles | ForEach-Object { Write-Host "$_" }, where`$_` includes the actual file-object in the pipeline).

If you want to filter for file-endings you can add the `-Include` parameter to `Get-ChildItem`. If you want to look for files in nested folders you can add the `-Recurse` switch.

So your above example can be simplified to one cmdlet call:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Doc\File" -Include "*US*0908*" -Recurse
```

Output:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Doc\File" -Include "*US*0908*" -Recurse


 Directory: C:\Doc\File

  Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
  ----                -------------         ------ ----
  -a----        16.07.2019    07:27              0 US0908ABC
  -a----        16.07.2019    07:27              0 US0908DEF
  -a----        16.07.2019    07:28              0 US0908GHI
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$Variable_1 = "US"
$Variable_2 = "0908"
$Path = "C:\Doc\File"
$SW = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path

for ($i=0; $i -lt $SW.Count; $i++) {

 $outfile = $SW[$i].FullName
 if($outfile -match $Variable_1 -and $outfile -match $Variable_2)
 {   $outfile
    Write-Host "Found"
 }
 else {
  $outfile
  Write-Host "Check Again!"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for files within the `$Path`, then this will do what you are after. You can confirm this by changing one of the files to from `US0908...` to `US0907...`.

```
$Variable_1 = "US"
$Variable_2 = "0908"
$Path = "C:\Doc\File"
$SW = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path

Foreach($File in $SW) {
    If(($File.Name -match $Variable_1) -and ($File.Name -match $Variable_2)) {
        Write-Host "Found"
    } Else {
        Write-Host "Check Again!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works if the file match and not match. But if the file not match, I want to make a looping to check it each 5 second until the file match. Because the file will generate from other process.
I tried with my updatd code, but it does not work, it always return found.